# Running minizinc from python with time-limit results in keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, minizinc, keyboardinterrupt

I am solving graph coloring problem using minizinc.
The process run looks loke

```py
mz_output = subprocess.run(["minizinc", "--time-limit",  "10000", "--no-intermediate", "-p 4", "graph_coloring.mzn", "data.dzn"], 
                                        shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

It works fine for some graphs, but for graph with 1000 nodes and ~250000 edges it throws `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "submit.py", line 458, in <module>
    main(parser.parse_args())
  File "submit.py", line 390, in main
    results = compute(metadata, args.override)
  File "submit.py", line 181, in compute
    submission = output(problem.input_file, solver_file)
  File "submit.py", line 222, in output
    solution = pkg.solve_it(load_input_data(input_file))
  File "D:\Coursera\Discrete\Coloring\coloring\solver.py", line 73, in solve_it
    shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 490, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "D:\programs\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I supposed it is connected with size of the graph but it doesn't appear so. First, it works fine in minizinc IDE and gives intermediate solutions in the first seconds. Second, it is expected some time errors or memory errors in case of large size, while `KeyboardInterrupt` is confusing. How I can resolve that issue?

Comment: Does it signal the interrupt on the time limit?

Comment: @Alex, no, it doesn't

Comment: Then, have you tried reading in a loop with `run.stdout.readline()`  ?, maybe the io buffer is getting too big

Comment: @Alex, reading what? The output of process is 1000 numbers, it shouldn't be too big.

Comment: @Nourless What happens if you add the MiniZinc flags `-a`, `-s`, and `-v` to trace the MiniZinc process? Does that give you any clues?